# How to set base path in laravel5.2?

Tags: php, url, laravel-5, environment-variables

I am new one to laravel, how can we set base URL in laravel

I want url looks like 
https://localhost/projectfolder/site/home

But when i click on link it goes to

https://localhost/home

Thanks in advance

Comment: Bit off topic, but please note that Laravel 5.2 hasn't been updated for two years. Consider upgrading to at least 5.5 LTS and preferably the most recent 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString
APP_URL='this is where you set the app url'
```

You can find this settings in the .env file in your root project folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have tried, but didn't works